# Joomla plugin install XML files <folder> tag

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla1.5

While developing a joomla plugin, if my plugin folder looks like so:

> /install.xml
>   /mainPg.php
>   /subfolder/lib.php
>   /subfolder/config.php

Would the  tag look like this?

```
<files>
    <filename plugin="mainPg">mainPg.php</filename>
    <folder>subfolder</folder>
</files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok. Did you test it?

For docs see: http://docs.joomla.org/Components:xml_installfile